# Calculate the blur degree with variance of laplacian in open cv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I try to obtain the blur degree of a image. I reference [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/) with calculating the variance of laplacian in open cv.

```
import cv2
def variance_of_laplacian(image):
  return cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()

def check_blurry(image):
  """
  :param: the image 
  :return: True or False for blurry
  """
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  fm = variance_of_laplacian(gray)
  return fm
```

When I try to calculate the fm from two images, which look exactly same but with different size.

```
filePath = 'small.jpeg'
image1 = cv2.imread(filePath)
print('small image shape', image1.shape)
print('small image fm', check_blurry(image1))

filePath = 'large.jpg'
image2 = cv2.imread(filePath)
print('large image shape', image2.shape)
print('large image fm', check_blurry(image2))
```

The output of is:

```
small image shape (1440, 1080, 3)
small image fm 4.7882723403428065
large image shape (4032, 3024, 3)
large image fm 8.44476634687877
```

Obviously, the small image is scaled down 2.8 ratio of large image. Is fm related to the size of image? If so, what's the relationship between them? Or is there any solution to evaluate the blur degree for different size images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Is fm related to the size of image?"*

Yes partially (at least in regard of your question), because if you scale an image, you have to interpolate pixel values. Downscaling will not only lose information but create *new* information by pixel interpolation (if it's not nearest-neighbor interpolation) and thus influence the variance of the resulting image. But this only applies to scaled images, not to images which are different in the first place.